# Comparing int values

Tags: python

Why is my code not letting me compare these 4 integers--- it just returns none? What am I doing wrong -- just a beginner

```
def isinRange(exonStartPos,   exonEndPos,  ChromListStartPos,  ChromListEndPos):
    inRange  = False
    if exonStartPos < ChromListStartPos & exonEndPos < ChromListEndPos:
        returnList = [inRange, 0 , 0]
        return returnList
    if exonStartPos > ChromListEndPos & exonEndPos> ChromListEndPos:
        returnList = [inRange, 0 , 0]
        return returnList
    if exonStartPos < ChromListStartPos & exonEndPos < ChromListEndPos:
        inRange = True
        returnList = [inRange, ChromListStartPos, exonEndPos]
        return returnList
    if exonStartPos > ChromListStartPos & exonEndPos > ChromListEndPos:
        inRange = True
        returnList = [inRange, exonStartPos, ChromListEndPos]
        return returnList
    if exonStartPos == ChromListStartPos & exonEndPos <= ChromListEndPos:
        inRange = True
        returnList = [inRange, exonStartPos, exonEndPos]
        return returnList
    if exonStartPos >= ChromListStartPos & exonEndPos == ChromListEndPos:
        inRange = True
        returnList= [inRange, exonStartPos, exonEndPos]
        return returnList


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ChromListRange = isinRange(665973, 666002, 745554,752391)
    print ChromListRange[0]
```

Comment: Shouldn't your code under your function definition be indented?

Comment: yes it is , sorry it must have been a copying error when I was inputing it on stack exchange

Comment: Please explain what the result should be, and fix your indentation (edit: sorry I had not seen the commentaries above)

Comment: Use the and keyword instead of &, you'e using the bitwise operator.

Comment: You should use "and" instead of "&" with booleans...

Comment: You need an `else` clause, or a final return.  You are  getting `None` because there is no return when it doesn't find a match.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to change your `&`s to `and`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Operator precidence.

Observe the following:

```
>>> 2 < 3 and 1 < 2
True
>>> 2 < 3 & 1 < 2
False
```

The first statement evaluates to:

```
(2<3) and (1<2)
True  and True
True
```

The second however evaluates to:

```
2 < (3 & 1) < 2
2 <    1    < 2
False
```

`a<b<c` is valid syntax in python (in a language like C, this would be a syntax error) so no error is thrown, you just get unexpected output.

Logical algebra should be done with `and` `or` and `not`, instead of the bitwise equivalents.